# Codename One: Choosing and Styling a Native Font

Tags: fonts, codenameone, native, derived

For my app I need a font that scales well with the device display size.
I tried but did not like the system fonts small, medium and large.
Specifying a size in mm is also unattractive because it has to be calculated for each device.
I found that I like the font of a native button (unselected) on both iOS and Android devices.
(On Android, native Labels, Buttons and TextFields have different font sizes; I want a uniform size.)
So I decided to use the native button font for all my text components.

Say I add UIID MyTextField to the theme and specify everything (background, colors, etc.) except the font.
The font I want to derive from a native Button.
However, the Developer Guide says (in 3.3.13): **'always inherit only from UIID’s you defined e.g. MyButton'**.
So how do you access the native Button font? I decided to set the font in code and that works:

```
// includeNativeBool == true
Font myFont = new Button().getUnselectedStyle().getFont();
...
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setUIID("MyTextField");
textField.getAllStyles().setFont(myFont);
```

Is this the correct solution? Or is there a way to handle the font in the Style?

Comment: P.S. I do not override Button in the theme but use my own MyButton etc.

Comment: If you like the native font, simply use that, at the size that you want. There is no need to use a code like the one you reported. The millimeter is the more natural way to set a size, you don't need to calculate anything, the actual size in pixels is calculated automatically. If you are curious to see how the native Android and iOS themes are styled, you can download the res files from: https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-skins/tree/master/Phones

Comment: Yes I now use "millimeters" (which are not real millimeters), see also the comments below the answer. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button font size is defined in millimeters in the themes for the respective OSs. MM size is uniform based on display density so it should be the closest thing to uniform size you can get.

What you did is a hack. It will work in theory but it looks ugly and will behave inconsistently and unpredictably as we change the underlying native theme design.

Comment: I don't understand why you say that it looks ugly. I tried on a number of devices (iPhone X, iPhone SE, iPhone 5, iPad 4, Nexus 5 tablet and a Samsung phone) and on a dozen of simulator skins (both iOS and Android) and it looks perfectly fine. The font size is approximately 2 mm on an iPhone X and 3 mm on an iPad (for example), which is exactly what I want.

Comment: If my implementation is viewed as a hack, can you offer this functionality in a way that it is not a hack? 
All I want to know (to derive) is the font or font size of a native button - or any other font that scales well with all devices. I don't see how using millimeters would help me, as they are absolute and not relative. And the system fonts are not scaled as well as native buttons.

Comment: Ugly as in a "hack" that doesn't fit. The "native" button style is in millimeters so there's literally no difference. Millimeters change based on device density so they are not absolute units.

Comment: I see. So I specify a true type font (e.g. "native:MainRegular 3 mm", no need to provide a .ttf file) in the theme and this will be scaled exactly like the native button font. This is indeed the functionality that I was looking for. Calling this "millimeters" is unfortunate. (Though I understand there were historical reasons.)

Comment: No. It is milometers. The size adapts to screen density unlike pixels of which you can have different amounts millimeters is a physical size used as a global standard.

Comment: Yes I know what a millimeter is. My point is that you should not use that word for something which is a different thing. Milometers is a better term I suppose, and I suggest that the software and documentation are updated accordingly. The word millimeters is used everywhere and there is no mention of milometers anywhere. You also used millimeters in the discussion up till now, which is confusing.